# SSH pauses - perhaps MTU/packet size too large - how to confirm and possibly resolve?

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, mtu

I have a MacOS client and Linux server (non-root access). I'm using 2 versions of a tool for remote desktop control. Version 2 worked pretty well - some small bugs. The vendor has updated to version 3. Version 3 fixes many bugs but has one major bug where the server updates will be paused for a few seconds or more as I'm working. This bug isn't acknowledged by the vendor, and they won't work to resolve it.
Both versions use ssh to launch the server application and communicate through the ssh tunnel. I suspect there is a packet size / MTU issue going on with version 3 and I've read that can cause pauses in ssh. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/412192/why-would-ssh-freeze-for-minutes-at-a-time-when-other-traffic-is-unaffected

1. Is there a way to confirm this kind of issue? I've tried running Wireshark, but I don't see how to confirm the issue.
2. Might I be able to write a user-mode program to wrap the server software in? Something that can change packet sizes?

I don't have root access to these servers, all of this software runs with user level privileges.